# Object literal property assignment oddity: what's happening here?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype, object-literal

I'm writing a unit test (in Mocha with Chai) to see if some object, `o` is an `instanceof` `ClassY`. The unit test succeeds, but I can make it fail depending on how I create an object literal, despite the fact that the produced object literal is the same.

That's a bit vague, I know. Let me explain more.

`ClassY` is part of an object, which we will call `Parent`. This relationship simply looks like this:

```
Parent: {
  ClassY: function() {}
}
```

I'm attaching `Parent` to `Backbone` using the Underscore extend method:
`_.extend( Backbone, Parent )`

This results in Backbone having the `ClassY` property, which can be accessed via `Backbone.ClassY`.

My unit test is:
`expect( o ).to.be.instanceof( Backbone.ClassY );`

where I know for a fact that `o` is an instance of `Backbone.ClassY`.

It **passes** if I write:

```
var Parent = {};
var ClassY = Parent.ClassY = function() {};
```

and also

```
var Parent = {};
var ClassY = function() {};
Parent.ClassY = ClassY;
```

But the unit tests **fails** when I write the following:

```
var ClassY = function() {};
var Parent = {  
  ClassY: ClassY  
};
```

The reason for failure is:

```
TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a valid argument for 'instanceof'
(evaluating 'flag(this, 'object') instanceof constructor')
```

Indeed, inspecting Backbone in Chrome DevTools reveals to me in the failing case, `ClassY` is an Object. In the cases of success it is the constructor.

I imagine this is some simple property of object literals that eludes me. Do you know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what Backbone is doing here (I've got a couple of ideas as to why that might happen, based on knowledge of various "Class"/inheritance implementations in JS, but I'd have to look at the library).

What I CAN tell you, however, is that it's something the library is doing, rather than something about objects, inherently.

Here is your proof:

```
var Parent_1 = {
        ClassX : function () { this.x = "x"; }
    },

    ClassY = function () { this.y = "y"; },

    Parent_2 = {
        ClassY : ClassY
    };


var littleX = new Parent_1.ClassX(),
    littleY = new Parent_2.ClassY();

littleX instanceof Parent_1.ClassX;
littleY instanceof Parent_2.ClassY;
```

Both of those should be true.

In JS, when you do something like :

```
var x = {}, y = [];
x.y = y;
```

You're giving it a reference to the exact same instance of that object (numbers/strings/booleans work differently).

So  `x.y === y` is true, while `{} === {}` is false, even if both objects have the same properties.

In backbone, I would imagine that you're passing it in, Backbone is finding a constructor and manipulating it to append helpers or hooks, or to add extra inheritance or MVC functionality/observation, et cetera.

So what comes through the other side isn't the exact same object, in memory -- that's probably buried in a closure, somewhere that Backbone can then poke at, and wire itself up to.  Again, haven't read the source, but that's my initial reaction.